# Как парсить информацию с другого сайта, заполняя там поля?

Tags: php, curl

Есть сайт университета и на нем есть расписание пар(http://bseu.by/schedule/), так вот хотелось бы парсить это расписание себе на сайт, а там просто для себя адаптироваться его. Но не полностью все расписание для всех, а только некоторые пункты(т.е. оно должно заполнять форму заранее описанными пунктами и получать расписание, которое бы уже копировалось на сайт). Как это можно реализовать с помощью PHP и cURL? И возможно ли? Надеялся, что GETом шлет, но нет, с виду никакой перезагрузки не происходит.

Comment: откройте в браузере консоль и смотрите, какие сетевые запросы проходят

Answer (score 2):

Задача элементарная.

1) Надо сделать анализ запросов.

В гугл браузер нажми F12, выбери вкладку networks. Затем в форме выбери тот запрос какой тебе нужен. Посмотри как он сделан, куда отправляется(post?get?).

Например, в текущем примере(http://bseu.by/schedule/) видно, что идет post запрос:

Request URL:http://bseu.by/schedule/
faculty:7
form:10
course:3
group:5757
tname:
period:1

2) Используй например curl. Тупо отправляй этот запрос. Смотри результат.

Вообщем то всё.

Comment: Какой запрос является нужным в этой вкладке? Он отправляет множество различных операций в секунду.

Comment: @StartProg, post request URL -> http://bseu.by/schedule/ with params -> faculty:7 form:10 course:3 group:5757 tname: period:1

Comment: А как это все реализовать на cURL? И даже если с отправкой POST вопросов не так много, ибо информация в интернете есть, то как получать это расписание себе на сайт?

Comment: @StartProg,вот пример post запроса с curl https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662831/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-php-curl. у тебя тоже самое, только другой запрос. а в index.php, пишешь echo resultFromPostRequst; // выводишь, то что получил в result. если нужно в нормальном читабельном виде? то добавляешь тег табличку и выводишь массив не строкой а по параметрам например, $shedule->class, $shedule->time.. и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Как понимаю, там обычный POST-запрос, который отправляет параметры поиска на сервер? В этом случае отправляйте напрямую в адрес, обрабатывающий POST-запросы нужные параметры и получайте готовый HTML.